# Is it acceptable to write "the function $f_n$ is cts for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$"?

Tags: proof-writing, terminology, article-writing

When I have a sequence of functions $f_n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, is it OK or acceptable to write

"The function $f_n$ is continuous for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$"

meaning

"For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the function $f_n$ is continuous"?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, at least I don't see any problem with that.

Comment: I was afraid it might be kinda weird to write "the function f_n" at a stage where it is not yet specified what n is.

Comment: It is not, you can do that without a problem. If you feel weird, something that is normally done is to write when you define the functions, not $f_n , n\in \mathbb{N}$, but $\{f_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ since it is a sequence.

Comment: The sequence of functions is properly defined before I discuss the continuity in my thesis. My problem is just the wording. But thank you, I feel much better about it now.

Comment: If at all, this is a natural language (here:English) question, and there it is not uncommon for a thing to be referenced that is described by a clause to follow at a moment that can best be called later

Comment: OK, thank you. I think I'm finally going to sleep well :-)

Comment: While the meaning is clear, it is poor English. In the context of the continuity there are many (distinct) functions, not just one. I would use the second statement or write something like "the functions $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are continuous".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing with symbols, the quantifiers ("for every natural $n$" / "$\forall n\in\Bbb N$") has to come before using the $n$ for something like referring to the functions $f_n$. When writing in English, it's common to let it come after, as long as it's still part of the same sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You should be okay in doing this provided 1. it's true (with justification?) and 2. it's clear from the context of your writing what the domain is of these functions.

Comment: Yes, both of the conditions are satisfied. It is just the wording which I was not sure about.